# Getting exponential values when using describe() in Python

Tags: python-3.x, describe

I am getting exponential output when i use the below describe function:

```
error_df = pandas.DataFrame({'reconstruction_error': mse,'true_class': 
dummy_y_test_o})
print(error_df)
error_df.describe()
```

I tried printing the values in error_df and the count is 3150. But why do i get a exponential value then?

```
      reconstruction_error  true_class
0                 0.000003           0
1                 0.000003           1

...                    ...         ...

3148              0.000003           2
3149              0.000003           0

[3150 rows x 2 columns]
Out[17]:
reconstruction_error    true_class
count   3.150000e+03    3150.000000
mean    3.199467e-06    1.000000
std 1.764693e-07    0.816626
min 2.914150e-06    0.000000
25% 3.058539e-06    0.000000
50% 3.092931e-06    1.000000
75% 3.423379e-06    2.000000
max 3.737767e-06    2.000000
```